# What does this custom URLClassLoader actualy do?

Tags: java, classloader

I've found this custom classloader that allows you to import multiple versions of a class from URLs.

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader{
private ChildClassLoader childClassLoader;

public CustomClassLoader(List<URL> classpath)
{
    super(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    URL[] urls = classpath.toArray(new URL[classpath.size()]);
    childClassLoader = new ChildClassLoader( urls, new DetectClass(this.getParent()) );
}

@Override
protected synchronized Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    try
    {
        return childClassLoader.findClass(name);
    }
    catch( ClassNotFoundException e )
    {
        return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
    }
}

private static class ChildClassLoader extends URLClassLoader
{
    private DetectClass realParent;

    public ChildClassLoader( URL[] urls, DetectClass realParent )
    {
        super(urls, null);
        this.realParent = realParent;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        try
        {
            Class<?> loaded = super.findLoadedClass(name);
            if( loaded != null )
                return loaded;
            return super.findClass(name);
        }
        catch( ClassNotFoundException e )
        {
            return realParent.loadClass(name);
        }
    }
}

private static class DetectClass extends ClassLoader
{
    public DetectClass(ClassLoader parent)
    {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        return super.findClass(name);
    }
}
}
```

It seems to work perfectly, but the problem is that my attempts of fully understanding what it actually does have been futile. The site that I've found it on ( https://dzone.com/articles/java-classloader-handling ) provides very minimal explanation and the code itself has zero comments.

I know what this code does overall and I've managed to deduce what's going on inside the CustomClassLoader constructor, but the rest of it is completely beyond my abilities.
Could any of you provide me with some insights on how this code actualy works?

Comment: Why not ask the author? DZone has a comment section. You can also google the author's name. I found their twitter handle and Stack Overflow Profile within minutes.

Comment: @Turing85 Well this just seemed like a less intrusive way of doing things. Why spam someone's DM's about an article that they wrote in 2014 when there is a website that allows you to ask these sorts of questions. Also I posted this here and not in the DZone comment section because I saw that it has been dead since 2019 and the author stopped responding to them in 2014.

Comment: Because as useful as Stackoverflow is, it is also your "last resort": you post to SO if you've run out of proper other places to ask (or you asked there, but it's yielded no results). Asking the author of the original code if they put it online for the world to use is perfectly fine: worst case they say "sorry I forgot, I haven't looked at this in a decade" and then you have a great using to post on SO. A dead forum is certainly a reason to post here, but if the author is easily reachable, reach out. Even if you do that in parallel: worse case, now you'll be able to post an answer yourself.

Comment: If you want to load multiple versions of a class, create new class loaders *with the correct parent*, i.e. a parent not knowing the other version. E.g. to load `clazz` again, use `clazz.getClassLoader().getParent()` as the new loader’s parent. The posted code is just horrible and perhaps, even the author does not understand what it does. The class `DetectClass` is entirely obsolete. The `ChildClassLoader` could simple call `loadClass` directly on the parent loader within its exception handler. Though even this is obsolete, as `CustomClassLoader`’s exception handler effectively does the same.